How to configure stockfish.js
I have been trying to use it had a lot of problems with it.
Tried to put the stockfish files in public file in my react, node and express app with vite. I tried to follow compiling instructions. I am not even sure if I need to compile it first with emscripten. Tried to use following structure in a jsx component:
useEffect(() => {
      engineWorker.current = new Worker('./stockfish.js');
      engineWorker.current.postMessage("uci");
      engineWorker.current.postMessage("ucinewgame");
      engineWorker.current.postMessage("position fen " + game.fen());
      engineWorker.current.postMessage("go depth 10");
      engineWorker.current.onmessage = (event) => {
        const message = event.data;
        if(message.startsWith("bestmove")) {
          const bestMove = message.split(" ")[1];
          const move = game.move(bestMove);
          setMsg("Best move is " + bestMove);
        }
      }
    }, [game]);


I found a stockfish.js file online and used that and it magically worked.
